# Linq select distinct

Tags: linq, select, distinct

I have a generic list of journeys which has a property in it of VehicleId and I want to get a list of distinct vehicle ids from the journey list

I have tried using the following:

```
Journeys.Select(j => new { j.FleetVehicleId }).Distinct();
```

but I have run into an error of

```
Expression cannot contain lambda expressions
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here or how to do this properly?

Comment: i think that you are trying to run your code in quick watch and in consequence you are getting that error. you can't debug lambda expressions into quick watch window. try to watch your code into debug. your code seems to be ok, but i would correct it and change it to Journeys.Select(j => j.FleetVehicleId).Distinct();

Comment: Thanks @lante, it was because I was trying to debug it to see what I was getting.  If you put an answer up I can mark it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are trying to debug your code into quick watch window and in consequence you are getting that error.

You can't debug lambda expressions into quick watch window. Try to debug your code after calling the lambda expression. For example:

```
var testing = Journeys.Select(j => j.FleetVehicleId).Distinct();
// debug testing value here, after lambda expression runs
```

The code seems to be ok.

Answer (score 2):

how about:

```
Journeys.Select(j => j.FleetVehicleId ).Distinct();
```

Comment: Isn't that still a lambda?

Comment: You can definitely use lambdas in Select() in normal C# code. See lante's comment.

Comment: i could imagine that the problem comes, if Journeys is not enumerable, so if it is a queryable object. then the distinct operation "decompiles" the expression. the construct in the question contains an anonymous object, which can create more error sources